# i cant create keystore in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keystore

I've follow the instruction but this message showed up

```
    keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)ecified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)       
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1194)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)
```

THE STEP I DID TO MAKE KEYSTORE :

```
    Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password: 
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:
Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
  [no]:  yes

Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days
        for: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Enter key password for <upload>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

and the message above showed up. i also couldnt find the file location of keystore. is that because its not created yet?

Comment: Share the steps you took to create keystore

Comment: Is the file name upload.jks or upload-keystore.jks ?

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\location_of_your_project\your_project\android\app\upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Answer (score 0):

run this command in your project terminal

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\Administrator\keystore\AppName-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

`C:\Users\Administrator\keystore\` here enter your folder path to save keystore file